# What is the purpose of prohibiting union coupler in concealed area?

Tags: pipe, natural-gas, fitting

I was reading about natural gas union coupler and left-right coupling vis a vis concealed locations.   Setting aside the seemingly mixed regs around the country regarding usage/prohibition of them, in general, it seems that the preferred (regulation-wise) union in concealed locations is the LR coupler.

As I understand it, having worked with neither (yet), LR couplers are tricky to install/seal.  As such, I'm puzzled as to why they are preferred in conceal areas.

Is union couplers even more tricky, or is it just the shear largeness/complexity of union couplers that make them undesirable in concealed locations?

Comment: I don't know that code gives the "why" of this but I'm sure it's due to the difficulty in inspecting a concealed coupler.

Comment: '[plumbing] conceal(ed)', yields no valid results, +1

Comment: I thought it was the threads having a possibility to loosen up without twisting the pipe but I did not remember street fittings not being allowed +

Answer (score 1):

Can't use bushings either (or street elbows, afaik). Presumably because of the existence of exterior threads *on a fitting* which makes it more subject to corrosion, each thread of which is an inherent shear plane.

"Caution: installing a bushing in a gas piping system in a concealed location can create a potentially explosive situation." – *Residential Construction Academy: Plumbing*, By Michael A. Joyce, Michael D. Joyce, [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=DD3ki3xIGEYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: You have to use *reducers* or *couplers*. They're "[required] in conceal areas" because concealed unions are prohibited, along with every other fitting that has exterior threads.